# Average gaming time and session frequency

Tags: group-dynamics

**Is there any (semi) hard data on average gaming time and session frequency?**

How often does an average party play and how long does an average session of theirs last?

Has anyone surveyed this yet (with publicly available results)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [market research by Wizards of the Coast](http://www.seankreynolds.com/rpgfiles/gaming/WotCMarketResearchSummary.html), taken in 1999:

7.2% of D&D players play monthly. (The report doesn't say whether this includes weekly.) Only 4.9% of new gamers who have played for under a year play monthly. 13.2% of players who have played for 1-5 years play monthly, and only 5.9% of those who played D&D for over five years played monthly. One hypothesis is that people often get into the game as teenagers, but have less time to play as they get older.

28% of D&D players play for more than five hours in a typical session. Among players who have played for a year or less, that number drops to 10%. Among who have played for 1-5 years, 14% play for longer than 5 hours. For people who have played for over five years, 42% play for more than five hours, but they tend to play less frequently.

These figures are from 1999, so it's mainly talking about AD&D and earlier.

Comment: I can't tell if those percentages are of all gamers (cards, computers, puzzles, board games etc) or a percentage of those who responded to playing RPGs

Comment: Note that the WotC market research is both [old and potentially flawed](http://trustrum.com/wotc-market-research/), but it's also true that we really don't have anything better :(

Answer (score 13):

In December, 2016, Mike Shea [compiled the results of a survey of 6,600 *Dungeons & Dragons* Dungeon Masters](http://slyflourish.com/2016_dm_survey_results.html). The survey inquired about a variety of subjects, including frequency of play and session duration.

**Frequency of Play**

- More than twice a week = 1.9%
- Twice a week = 6.2%
- Weekly = 43.2%
- Twice a month = 25.9%
- Monthly = 13.3%
- Less than monthly = 9.6%

**Session Duration**

- About an hour = 0.5%
- About two hours = 5.0%
- About three hours = 28.4%
- About four hours = 43.9%
- About six hours = 16.7%
- About eight hours = 3.7%
- Longer than eight hours = 1.7%

Note that these survey results are focused on *Dungeons & Dragons*, and the usual caveats about selection bias apply. The survey is a treasure-trove of information though, and Shea has taken great pains to make all the underlying data accessible.