# Are there statistics of the more played games?

Tags: games-industry, statistics

Looking the questions of this site, it seems that D&D, in all its versions and variants, is by far the most played game. But that's not quite true of the people I know, so I think the proportions in Europe and USA may be different.

Are there any real statistics about the most played games? I'm specially interested in per-country or at least per-continent statistics.

Comment: Related questions (both mine, both rather unsuccessful): [List of top fantasy RPGs](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/9017/list-of-top-fantasy-rpgs-answer-based-on-hard-data) and [Average gaming time and session frequency](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/9754/average-gaming-time-and-session-frequency)

Comment: I've seen someone cite retail sales numbers before, so those should be available?  You could also look at the Amazon ranking of various core books, but I'm not sure how helpful that should be.

Comment: [ICv2](http://www.icv2.com) occasionally publishes/ranks sales information, which probably correlates with play for newer games.

Answer (score 7):

### The Orr Group Industry Report

Every quarter, [Roll20](https://roll20.net/) releases statistics on what systems are played on their platform. This is [Q3 2021](https://blog.roll20.net/posts/the-orr-report-q3-2021/):

[image: most popular by percentage of campaigns]

In percents: 53.7 D&D 5e, 19.8 uncategorized, 11.9 Call of Cthulhu, 11.5 all others, 3.2 Pathfinder, 1.4 Pathfinder 2e, .9 Warhammer, .9 World of Darkness, .8 D&D 3.5e, .6 Starfinder, .6 Tormenta.

This is helpful to compare similar systems, ones that require something like Roll20 to play. It's not so great at being comprehensive. In particular, what about the systems that don't require Roll20 to play? (For example, I play Dungeon World entirely in theater of the mind.) It also doesn't give you a further breakdown, but a virtual game might not be played in only one country anyway (mine aren't, not even the same continent).

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there's a great deal of published, general information on this topic.

Among podcast listeners, there's an [annual survey](https://web.archive.org/web/20140211075348/http://spookyouthouse.com:80/files/survey/Podcast_Listener_Survey_Results_and_Analysis_2012.pdf) that includes what games listeners are playing. Informally, I would assume that RPG podcast listeners probably play a broader range of RPGs than the gaming population as a whole. [Jennisodes has a discussion of the survey results.](https://web.archive.org/web/20150322190703/http://www.jennisodes.com/podcasts/rpg-listener-survey/)